# Aside from going 2-5 years between "upgrades", what do I give up by jumping off LTS?

Tags: upgrade, lts

I've been using LTS versions of Ubuntu for several years (14.04 at first, now 16.04), and have never had a successful `do-release-upgrade`; I've understood this is because I run a lot of third-party software.

I've done things this way because I prefer to keep the same interface over a period of time, instead of having to learn new ways of doing things every six months.  What I lose from this is that new software sometimes won't run on a 3-5 year old version of Ubuntu, despite it still being "supported."  My current case is that I want to install an add-on that requires C++17 support, which wasn't available when 16.04 was frozen and hasn't been added in backports (as far as I've been able to find).

In fact, the support I need is apparently only available in 19.04 and newer versions; even upgrading (painfully) to 18.04 won't let me run what I want to run, because I still won't get the versions of libc++ and libc++abi that I need.

Question is, what else do I give up by switching to the twice-a-year standard release schedule, in return for having to install clean every six months (since upgrades *still* won't work due to the software I want/need on my machine).

Comment: Perhaps question should be how to install c++17?

Comment: Mostly time required to re-install (in your case; I assume using existing partitions without format so existing setup & user files aren't touched). Yet get newer programs & features (XFCE for example came out with features I loved in 17.10 cycle I'd not want to live without).  Slight time loss as you look at new features (or on rare occasion, what's gone or changed) but that'll vary on how much you explore your system.  More bandwidth used as you'll get more updates (esp. when releases are 'fresh') though still far less than development release.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using ubuntu since Warty in 2004 and I always upgraded every six months.
Incremental upgrades are always a bit tricky in my experience. You need to carefully prepare your system before the jump and sometimes what you get is not as polished as a fresh ubuntu installation. That's why I usually proceed with a fresh installation each time. I keep a separate /home partition and I just format my / partition every six months. After the upgrade I just apt install my favourite apps and everything works like before. I'm not saying you should do the same, but for sure jumping from LTS to LTS every two years will result in bigger jumps (and an increased risk of failing upgrades).

In my opinion you shouldn't be afraid of frequent upgrades. LTSes can be more stable in the long run (errors will be fixed down the road) but not at the beginning of each cycle, so even if you jump from LTS to LTS, you're not getting a dramatically different experience than upgrading every six months.

Comment: Honestly, my biggest peeve is that the interface (with whatever DTE you use) changes with every upgrade, and invariably the DTE I like get discontinued or nerfed (like KDE did beween its versions 4 and 5).  I have to spend my play/work time learning the new way of doing X, and doing that twice a year seems like four times the time loss vs. every other year.

Comment: I think it mostly depends on the DE you use and the frequency of your upgrades. Is is actually true that changes can be more visible when you upgrade from LTS to LTS. (Two years is a lot of time in the ever changing world of linux!). I don't use KDE, but I can testimony that GNOME is not changing that much from version to version. If you want something more traditional I recommend MATE: It's been pretty much the same for the last 10 years. You can't go wrong with it (I also recommend ubuntu MATE if you choose to give it a shot).

Comment: I'm actually currently on MATE, but I don't include it in the question(s) because 16.04 MATE apparently isn't LTS (never mind that I'm still getting updates almost daily).  And the MATE page seems to indicate some significant interface changes from 16.04 to 18.04.

Comment: "In my opinion you shouldn't be afraid of frequent upgrades."  This is kind of like a "don't have that problem" answer -- not, in itself, very helpful.

Comment: Changes from MATE 16.04 to 18.04 are mostly "under the hood" and will not impact your daily work. They basically upgraded the underlying technologies but they didn't change the user experience.

Comment: Sorry if my previous answer wasn't helpful. It's not, however, a "don't have that problem" answer. You asked "what do I give up by jumping off LTS" and i said "you're missing the stability of a two years old, well tested software". Do you like it more now?

Comment: If I'm not getting a dramatically different experience, then getting that experience 1/4 to 1/10 as often seems like a plus...

Comment: I'm not saying there are no differences at all: things are being refined, polished and debugged. Those "under the hood" changes can have an impact on speed, power consumption. There are also new functionalities that are being introduced step by step: you'll get them eventually anyways if you wait for two years. It all depends on how well the LTS release works for you. If you like your LTS, just stay there and upgrade once every two years. It's really up to you...